# best way to find the number of files in a directory in unix

Tags: linux, unix

For counting the number of files in directory i know two methods 
first one  `ls -l file* |wc -l`
second one `find file* -type f  -maxdepth 1 | wc -l`
which one is more relibale and correct one?

Comment: This isn't a question, it's a request for opinion.  Both samples work, which is _better_ is entirely dependent on how you're using them.

Comment: I would always use `ls file* | wc -l`. It feels more efficient. Note - that is a "opinion", which is not a good thing on SO. We should have hard data. But I'm not sure what metric you want to apply "more reliable and correct". By what measure?

Comment: Duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90106/whats-the-most-resource-efficient-way-to-count-how-many-files-are-in-a-director

Comment: These commands are not equivalent. The `ls` includes directories and  symlinks while the `find` does not. And the `find` includes hidden files while the `ls` does not.

Comment: @AlexHowansky what you mean by symbolic links?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Comment: This is NOT a matter of opinion. `ls` is designed for listing directories and `find` is designed for finding files in a directory tree. `ls` is the right way and most portable solution without a shadow of a doubt.

Comment: You should [never parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @janos: I agree with your first two sentences - how does the last sentence follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer the `find` option, but use `-name 'file*'` (in single quotes), as in

`find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'file*' -type f | wc -l`

This will avoid globbing, as both examples above I believe may run into a max args limitation.

```
`/home/charles/data/Study$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name CL* -type f | wc -l
bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long
`/home/charles/data/Study$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name `CL*` -type f | wc -l
318480
```

There is no such solution for `ls`, so `find` is slightly more dependable. This is all dictated by ARG_MAX, as in:

```
`/home/charles/data/Study$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152 # in bytes
```